# Server Writing Blank Files

Tags: web-server, filesystems, files

I have an old desktop that sits on the side of my desk at my office.  I use this as a web server to demo websites (it doesn't host any "live" production sites).  I've never had many issues with it until recently.

Out of the blue, the web server is no longer able to write files.  For example, when trying to upload a file from a website on the server.  The file will be created, but will be completely empty.  This is what occurs in any instance where the server is trying to write a file.

I can successfully upload files myself through FTP, but any time the server is trying to write the file itself, I end up with a blank file.

I searched for an answer, but have not been able to find any reference to this sort of problem, let alone a solution.

Comment: Do you want to tell us anything _about_ this web server?

Comment: What is helpful to know? It is running Apache 2.2.16 on Debian 6.0.3
Do you need to know specs?  Sorry, I'm more of a programmer/coder, not too knowledgable with these types of things.  I actually didn't set up the server myself either.

Comment: OK, well, it's time to check all your logs. System logs and apache logs. May as well see if you have a full disk, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file that's created empty, when it was meant to contain data, usually means that the disk (or disk partition) is full and so the file could not be extended past zero bytes. Check the output of `df -h` to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was actually just trying to post the output of that in a readable way.  It looks like I do have a full partition.  It says the full partition is mounted on /data.  When I look in /data, I have a "home" directory and "lost+found" directory.  The "home" directory looks like an exact copy of my /home directory.  I'm not sure why it would be set up this way, like I said, I didn't set it up myself.

Comment: to clarify, the /home directory is where all the websites are stored.

Comment: Sounds like you have a nice big cleanup job ahead of you. Better rent a backhoe. :)